# How to Prove the Chain Rule for Limits Using a $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ Argument?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, alternative-proof, epsilon-delta

I came across the chain rule for limits the other day and it interested me quite a bit and surprisingly I couldn't find the proof on the internet anywhere. From what I understand the chain rule for limits states that if:

$$ \lim_{x\to c} g(x)=M$$ and $$\lim_{x\to M} f(x)=L$$ then$$\lim_{x\to c} \ f(g(x))=L$$

*1.Under what conditions does this hold true?*

*2.What is the **epsilon-delta proof** for the rule?*

Comment: @user I was hoping to get only simpler understanding of this. I'm only beginning my second year as an undergrad. Is this a proof that can only be done with higher analysis?

Comment: Not really a duplicate in so far as the answer gives a sequential proof, whereas an epsilon-delta proof is requested here.

Comment: See http://www.supermath.info/OldschoolCalculusII.pdf page 83.

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: if you want to preserve your question and my answer, just ask the question again with a focus on the epsilon delta proof. In a different time it may survive. It is a reasaonable question.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Hi there, I think this is not really a duplicate! In this question an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof is requested while in the other question a sequential proof is requested! Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Claim:** Suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L_1$ and $\lim_{y \rightarrow L_1} g(y) = L_2$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g ( f(x)) = L_2$.

**Proof:** Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta >0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L_1|< \delta_2$ where $\delta_2 >0$ is small enough to force $|g(y)-L_2| < \epsilon$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < |y-L_1| < \delta_2$.

We can choose $\delta_2 > 0$ as above because we were given that $\lim_{y \rightarrow L_1} g(y) = L_2$. Further, we can also choose $\delta >0$ to force $|f(x)-L_1| < \delta_2$ because we were also given that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L_1$.

Suppose that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ and observe that $|g(f(x))-L_2 | < \epsilon$. Therefore, by the definition of the limit, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g ( f(x)) = L_2$. 
$\Box$

Thanks to Vim for correcting comment. Let me attempt a modified proof, it may be useful to locate the error in the logic above,

**Modified Claim:** Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) =L_1$ and $\lim_{y \rightarrow L_1} g(y) = L_2 = g(L_1)$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g ( f(x)) = L_2$.

**Modified Proof:** Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)=L_1$ it follows that for each $\delta_2 >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0 < |x-a|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-L_1| < \delta_2$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and pick $\delta_2>0$ such that $0< |y-L_1|< \delta_2$ implies $|g(y)-L_2| < \epsilon$. This choice of $\delta_2$ is possible since we are given that $\lim_{y \rightarrow L_1} g(y) = L_2$.

Suppose that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-L_1| < \delta_2$. Thus, for $y=f(x)$,we have $|y-L_1|< \delta_2$. We don't quite have what is needed to conclude just yet since we need $0<|y-L_1| < \delta_2$ in order to conclude $|g(y)-L_2|=|g(f(x))-L_2 | < \epsilon$. Consider two cases:

1. $0=|y-L_1|$ in which case $y=L_1$ hence $|g(L_1)-L_2| = |g(L_1)-g(L_1)| = 0 < \epsilon$
2. $0< |y-L_1|<\delta_2$ in which case we have $|g(y)-L_2|=|g(f(x))-L_2 | < \epsilon$

Hence, in all cases possible,$0 < |x-a| < \delta$ implies $|g(f(x))-L_2|< \epsilon$. Therefore, by the definition of the limit, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g ( f(x)) = L_2$. 
$\Box$

Of course, we can also state this result as it is often applied: the continuity of the outer function allows us to *pull the limit inside out*:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(f(x)) = g \left( lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \right)$$
where once again I should emphasize, the continuity of $g$ at $lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ is assumed.

Comment: This is not true.  You need extra conditions. For example, let $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $g(y)=0,y\ne 0,g(0)=1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV let a=1 for example. f(x) tends to 0 as x tends to a. So L1 is 0. g(y) tends to 0 as y tends to L1=0, so L2=0. But g(f(x)) is always 1.

Comment: @Vim Can I implore you to give the answer you feel is better or make changes to this one. Thanks

Comment: @Vim Yes.  So continuity of the "outer function" or the inner function never equals its limit except, possibly at the limit point, for some neighborhood of the limit point.  And this latter is violated in your example.  So, yes.  You are correct. We need some added assumption to ensure validity.

Comment: @Red For a quite strong condition, you can impose continuity at $L_1$ upon the outer function. In most cases it can be met.

Comment: @Vim Thanks I'll process that. The question was marked as duplicate when I dont feel it is so. Do you think it is a duplicate because you seem to know about the subject well enough?

Comment: @Red No. I don't think it's a dupe since you might have not learned the equivalence between sequential and epsilon-delta definitions yet. I hope I could reopen it for you but pitifully I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @Vim No worries as long as that confirms it isn't. Thanks!

Comment: @Vim You're confused. In your example, $g(y)$ has no limit when $y \to 0$. Look carefully at the definitions of what "$\lim_{y \to 0} g(y) = 0$" and you'll see that it's not satisfied. It is possible to modify the definition so that $g$ has a limit in your example, but it's a different definition (and not a very useful one in most cases), typically it's denoted $\lim_{\underset{y \neq 0}{y \to 0}} g(y)$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The most common definition of limit requires a punctured neighbourhood, i.e. $y\ne 0$ in this example. The point that the variable tends to doesn't even have to lie in the domain of definition, for example $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)/x=1$. I've never heard of a definition of limit that doesn't specifically require a punctured  neighbourhood.

Comment: @Vim This is a matter of convention, and I don't think it's "the most common" definition. Maybe it's because I'm French, the English Wikipedia takes a punctured neighborhood, the French one takes a full neighborhood for example. In $\lim (\sin x)/x$ this couldn't mean anything else but a punctured neighborhood so the meaning is not ambiguous. Anyway I think it's bad form to say a proof is "not true" when in fact you simply disagree with the notation, and the proof is actually correct if you interpret the notation as the answerer intended (and the notation isn't exactly outlandish)...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi it's not about the notation. I think it's about the details and it *matters*.  If one only cares about the "main idea" then the proof is acceptable, but "main idea" is in some sense far from enough for mathematical discussion.

Comment: @Vim Of course the notation matters...! The statement "If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = b$ and $\lim_{y \to b} g(y) = c$ then $\lim_{x \to a} g(f(x)) = c$" is true if you interpret the notation $\lim_{x \to a}$ as the limit with a full neighborhood, but untrue if it's for a deleted neighborhood. How can you say that notation doesn't matter in this situation? It completely changes whether the statement is true or not! The proof is perfectly acceptable, rigorous and mathematically correct as long as you interpret the notation correctly.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I was not saying the notation doesn't matter. What I tried to say was that we **should** care about details, which this proof failed to pay attention to, assuming the definition of limit does require a punctured neighbourhood (since the answer didn't mention anything specific about it I just assume it's using the traditional definition and notation) .

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Btw I'm curious about your definition that doesn't require a deleted neighbourhood so would you care to give some reference for this kind of definition?

Comment: @Vim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Deleted_versus_non-deleted_limits

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks for comments, sadly, in the case of my answer I had assumed a deleted limit (if you read my notes which I would not expect...). So, Vim's criticism was on point. I hope my modified proof clarifies why the continuity of the outside function is needed. Naturally, the counter example Vim gave picks at precisely the same weak point in my initial (wrong) proof.

Comment: @Vim Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook you are welcome

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks for the reference